# How to select div class item from 4th to last by XPath?

Tags: python, xpath

I'm trying to get `<div class="item">` from 5th to last by XPath.

I tried `//div[@class="list"]/div[5:]`,
`//div[@class="list"]/div[5:-1]`,
`//div[@class="list"]/div[5:20]`,
not working.

Please tell me how to get them. Thanks

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item">...</div> # 1
    <div class="item">...</div> # 2
    <div class="item">...</div> # 3
    <div class="item">...</div> # 4
    <div class="item">...</div> # 5
    <div class="item">...</div> # 6
    <div class="item">...</div> # 7
    <div class="item">...</div> # 8
    <div class="item">...</div> # 9
    <div class="item">...</div> # 10
    <div class="item">...</div> # 11
    <div class="item">...</div> # 12
    <div class="item">...</div> # 13
    <div class="item">...</div> # 14
    <div class="item">...</div> # 15
    <div class="item">...</div> # 16
    <div class="item">...</div> # 17
    <div class="item">...</div> # 18
    <div class="item">...</div> # 19
    <div class="item">...</div> # 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="list"]/div')[5:]
```

Comment: It seems like my python get some trouble with others, I did same as yours. Let me try again after re-install python. Thanks for your comment.